# .net temp table issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework-core, .net-3.0

I got an c# .net core project with an model called Sensor.

```
public class Sensor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long timestamp { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public string country { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Region")]
    public string region { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Emitter")]
    public string emitter { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

i need to get the following data:

the combination off country and region (call it tag) and its occurrences.
on that tag, add the emitter and count the occurrences separately.

Ex:

> usa.south- 1000
>
> usa.south.sensor01 - 700
>
> usa.south.sensor02 - 300
>
> canada.north- 1500
>
> canada.north.sensor01 - 1250
>
> canada.north.sensor02 - 250

My original idea was to use and temp table to hold the values, but its not working.

```
CREATE TABLE _Results (Tag Varchar(150), Total Int)

INSERT INTO[_Results] (Tag, Total)"  
SELECT country  '.'  region AS Tag, COUNT() AS Total
FROM Sensor
GROUP BY country, region

INSERT INTO[_Results](Tag, Total)
SELECT country  '.'  region  '.'  emitter AS Tag, COUNT() AS Total
FROM Sensor
GROUP BY country, region, emitter

SELECT * FROM _Results

DROP TABLE _Results
```

But i cant get this to work.

Can someone help me? An Memory usage solution is not available, so i got to use the SQL and the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Welcome to SO! as @corradolab pointed out, the community will be better able to assist you if you are specific about what is not working along with the troubleshooting steps you have already taken.  See this link for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I can't elaborate a query to the database using the entityframework to get the correct data and pass it to the view. So, I had the idea to use the temp table with this sql code above, but I can't make it work for anything. From what I researched, .NET does not work very well with temporary tables, so i`m asking if there is another solution or an way to make this work

Answer (score 1):

No need for temporary tables

```
SELECT country + '.' + region AS Tag, '' as Emitter, COUNT() AS Total
FROM Sensor
GROUP BY country, region
UNION
SELECT country + '.' + region AS Tag, Emitter, COUNT() AS Total
FROM Sensor
GROUP BY country, region, emitter
```

Create an entity for Tag, Emitter and Total.
Let's call it Statistic.
Declare a dbset in your DBContext

```
public virtual DbSet<Statistic> Statistics { get; set; }
```

Run the above SQL with FromSql and AsNoTracking

```
    query = context.Statistics
    .FromSql(sql)
    .AsNoTracking();
```

sql is the above SQL query saved in a string.

Comment: just one more thing man, the errors are gone, but the query is not returning the correct values.
     ``

Comment: I made an foreach loop in to check the query results and it returned this: Tag = 0
Emitter = 
Total = 1
Tag = 0
Emitter =
Total = 2
Tag = 0
Emitter =
Total = 4
Tag = 0
Emitter =
Total = 6
Tag = 0
Emitter = sensor01
Total = 2
Tag = 0
Emitter = sensor01
Total = 4
Tag = 0
Emitter = sensor02
Total = 2
Tag = 0
Emitter = sensor03
Total = 1

Comment: I checked the database, the values on table are correct

Comment: Found the issue, in the sql " country + '.' + region ", use || instead of +